# Modifying a file text

Tags: python, file, text-files, conditional-statements

I have a text file like this:

```
0  1  0  10.2  5.82  4.82
1 -1  0  8.21  5.74  3.62
0  1  1  5.33  8.66  5.47
```

This text file has a few hundred rows with this pattern.

In the first row, if the first column is 0, the fourth column is same. The second column is 1, the fifth column has +10, so the value 15.82.

In the second row, if the first column is 1, the forth column has +10, so the value is 18.21. The second column is -1, the fifth column has -10, so the value is -4.26. etc.

The final output is like this:

```
10.20  15.82  4.82
18.21  -4.26  3.62
 5.33  18.66  15.47
```

I have tried using this code that I wrote:

```
with open('abc') as f, open('out.txt', 'w') as f1:
    for line in f:
        reff = line.split()

        if reff[0] == '0':
            value = float(reff[3])
            a = str(value)
            line = "".join(a) + " " + "".join(reff[4]) + " " + "".join(reff[5]) + '\n'

        elif reff[0] == '1':
            value = float(reff[3]) + 10
            a = str(value)
            line = "".join(a) + " " + "".join(reff[4]) + " " + "".join(reff[5]) + '\n'

        elif reff[0] == '-1':
            value = float(reff[3]) - 10
            a = str(value)
            line = "".join(a) + " " + "".join(reff[4]) + " " + "".join(reff[5]) + '\n'

        f1.write(line)
```

I have also added more `if` and `elif` statements inside each `if` and `elif` statements in order to check the second column and the third column. However, only the fourth column was updated.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code you posted only updates the 4th column, so if you need help with updating the 5th and 6th columns you should probably post the code for those. I just tested it on my machine and it seems to update that column correctly. That said, do you have `write` statements in each of the `if-elif` blocks? That is, do you have a `write` for each of the 4th, 5th, and 6th column?

Comment: I actually added another if and elif statements inside each if and elif statements. In order to update 5th and 6th colume, I added like value = float(reff[4]), b = str(value), line = "".join(reff[3]) + " " + "".join(b) + " " + "".join(reff[5]) + '\n'. But nothing happened .

Comment: Well one thing that is going wrong is that you're overwriting the 4th column with `reff[3]` again -- you're undoing the work you did when you set it with `"".join(a)`. What I would try is calculating `a`, `b`, and `c` for columns 4, 5, and 6, then writing them all at once like this: `line = "".join(a) + " " + "".join(b) + " " + "".join(c) + '\n'`. It would really be easier for everyone to help if you posted all of your code.

Comment: OK. I guess that would work. I am now trying that.

Comment: Although, take a look at the answer posted by FMcC -- it's a little simpler. Happy coding! :)

Comment: Ok it works fine using if (if (if)), elif (if (if)) .... then update all value you comments. Thanks. However, FMcC's comments is much much simpler than mine. Mine has 100 lines, but his has only 6 lines. I am quite shamed. :-( Anyway, Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can actually be done very simply:

```
with open('abc') as f, open('out.txt', 'w') as f1:
    for line in f:
        line = line.split()
        for i in range(0,3):
            line[i+3] = float(line[i+3])+(int(line[i])*10)
        f1.write(' '.join([str(value) for value in line[3:]]) + '\n')
```

Which will give you as output:

```
10.2 15.82 4.82
18.21 -4.26 3.62
5.33 18.66 15.47
```

Comment: Thank you for posting a very simple code for this problem. I learnt a lot how to simplify the idea. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('abc.txt') as f, open('out.txt', 'w') as f1:

    modifyDict = { 0:0,
                   1:10,
                  -1:-10}


    for line in f:
        reffLine = line.split()

        reffInfo = []
        for i, reff in enumerate(reffLine[:3]):
            criteria = int(reff)
            value = float(reffLine[i+3]) + modifyDict[criteria]
            a = str(value)
            reffInfo.append(a)

        templine = " ".join(reffInfo)
        line = templine + '\n'

        f1.write(line)
```

This works in python 2.7. I created my own abc.txt and the results matched the output you wanted.

Comment: Thank you for your code. This can be also a good reference for my next coding. Thank you again.